# Reference to file regardless of the folder structure and depth

Tags: php, coding-style, menu

My research has lead me to believe that it **might** be called, **absolute URL / relative URL**. But please, I am not sure. So this is not reason to give me a minus as I have just reached 50 and I am on a STEEP learning curve.

In my index.php

I have a reference to a csv array. `/array/test.csv`

Then, I have a folder called **MENU**. In this folder I have a PHP called menu.php which also needs to make reference to the test.csv. However I **Cannot** put `/array/test.csv`, instead I have to put `../array/test.csv`.

So depending where you are in a folder structure, you might have to use `/ or ../ or ../../`,

Can someone point out the correct way to do this as I know that I will have problem if I do not learn the correct way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would call the full path of the file.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/array/test.csv"
```

The beginning says where the htdocs folder for your web server is.  Then we add the rest of the path from there.

So to store the path in a variable you may do.

```
$csvFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/array/test.csv"
```

Comment: So you can do this anywhere.... and it would work? e.g.  <?php include "../i-modules.php"; ?>

Comment: @Arthor, this isn't necessary unless you really need it, you can reference files **relative** or **absolute**. The `$_SERVER` method adds a prefix to your relative path and makes it absolute.

Comment: @thenetimp - I am going to try that and also, welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes you can do it anywhere.  Includes, requires, it's all linking to the absolute path of the file it would look something like.

    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/myincludedfile.php');

Comment: @Jakub - Great. I am going to give it a go and try it. I will play around and report back. Thank you

Comment: Jakub is right there is no right or wrong way to do it.  It's all preference at the end of the day.  If you are going to link to a file often in your code absolute may make sense, but if you only need the file once, or if ever file that you link to it uses the same depth then relative may work fine as well.

Comment: @thenetimp & @Jakub - Does Jakub have an effect of performance, I am just curios. @Jakub - I do agree that there is not ONE perfect way but there is always a good code or practice, it seems for me anyway that `['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Arthor, there is no correct way, you are correct it is `relative` vs `absolute` reference to a file/url/resource.

There is no wrong way. However each approach has its upsides, and downsides:

**Key difference points:**

- **relative:** portability (you can move your app by copy & paste somewhere else, as you call URLS `../array/file.ext` you will always refer to them correctly.
- **relative:** moving a file that makes reference to a resource relatively means you have to update its reference, if file was in `/file/folder/stuff/file.ext` and you move it, you need to update the reference to your `/array/file.ext` then.
- **absolute:** less portable, unless you use it in a URL sense (include javascript / images, etc)
- **absolute:** moving files that reference other files, means you don't have to change their code.
- and many more...

Personally I prefer absolute, but really it depends on your reasoning, neither of which is wrong.

Oh and to clarify (if you didn't know) `../` simply means "go down one directory, and then look from there, it is used in a relative link, where you outline where the file is *relative* to your script that is calling it.

Comment: But, can you not make the first part of the URL as a variable so  you only need to change that in the future.

Comment: @Arthor, if you make it a variable, it will effectively be **absolute**, but yes, you *can* do it, programming allows you to do so, its not right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` it depends on your folder structure. ".." means that you go one folder back.

If you have this structure:

```
root_dir
|
folderA
|  |
|  - A.php
|
folderB
   |
   - B.php
```

If you are in file B.php and want to include A.php you have to use this path:

```
inlcude "../folderA/A.php";
```

so you go one folder back, then you are in the `root_dir` from where you can access `A.php` via `folderA/A.php`.

Comment: so it is better to use `DOCUMNET_ROOT`as a better means of coding.

Comment: I would use the DOCUMNET_ROOT variant, so you don't have to care about the relative path.

Comment: Your way of explaining my problem is great!!! It seems that `DOCUMNET_ROOT` is the way to go. I agree there is NO ONE correct way but there are good codes or practices. Thus, this is one.

Comment: Yes, you can do both, nothing is right or wrong, but imo using the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is better readable and you can avoid messing around with with the relative paths, because this is getting more complex if you have many includes or if you include files that are included in others.

Comment: Does ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  have an effect of performance, I am just curios opposed to relative urls

Comment: I don't think this will effect the performance, you can read more about the [$_SERVER array here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and other information you can obtain.